# How to get line-wrapped text from JTextArea into multiple line-seperated Strings

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, word-wrap

I have a `JTextArea` with the following properties:

```
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
```

In the GUI the text is wrapped normally but when I call  `textArea.getText();` a single line of text is returned with no line separators.

My question is how can I get the text from the text area component 'as it is in the GUI' into a `String` or an array of strings?

Image Example:

[image]

Comment: *"My question is how can I get the text from the JTextArea component 'as it is in the GUI' into a String or an array of Strings?"*  My questions is:  **Why** could you possibly want that?  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: BTW - you do realize that where the line is broken depends not only on the size of the font as well as the width of the GUI, but also whether it is a 'fixed width' font.  The only use of this I could think of is for text that will be displayed using a fixed width font (e.g. a `txt` file opened in Notepad).  (And that text area is **not** using a fixed width font, and they are relatively easy to line break even without any GUI components).

Comment: You could get the text as _image_. Make a BufferedImage with the correct size, and pass its `createGrapics()` to the text area's paint.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I intend to use that text as a ToolTip text in another Component. Therefore I need the text not to be too long but break down in lines so it can be readable.

You are right about the XY problem, my fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get width of JTextArea via `textArea.size.width`, then get font metrics of JTextArea via `textArea.getGraphics().getFontMetrics(textArea.getFont())`, using FontMetrics you can calculate width of a particular string - `fontMetrics.stringWidth("Some string here")`.

Then you can, for example, add symbols of text one by one until you surpass width of JTextArea - and start a new line when you do.

I.e.

```
final String fullText = textArea.getText();
final int width = textArea.size.width;
final ArrayList lines = new ArrayList();
final FontMetrics fontMetrics = textArea.getGraphics().getFontMetrics(textArea.getFont());

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
for(final Character c : fullText) {
    sb.append(c);
    if(fontMetrics.stringWidth(sb.toString()) > width) { 
        sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1); 
        lines.add(sb.toString()); 
        sb = new StringBuilder(c.toString()); 
    }
}
lines.add(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Your idea was very helpful and I managed to break the lines down just as I wished.

Comment: it should work, but what about performance? calculate fontmetrics for each character?

Comment: Well, since this method will hardly be called a lot - it might be good enough.