# Line wraped JTextArea Java

Tags: java, jtextarea, line-breaks, word-wrap, line-count

I have a `JTextArea` with a fixed size and the `JTextArea` is allowed to wrap the lines and words.

I'm trying to get the last word before the `JTextArea` break the line.

Is there a way to get it?

I already try to use `lineCount()`, `getStartOffset()`, `getEndOffset()` and `getRows()`. I know how long my text is, how many characters it has. `lineCount` always `return 1`.

I was thinking about a change to get the possible character length for the `JTextArea`, or to find the break informations in the string, but there are no methods for it.

Did anyone has a Idea to get it?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31519905/994125) might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some untested code to give you an idea.

Since you know the size of the text area you can use the model/view methods of the text area to get the text.

```
int width = textArea.getSize().width;
int height = textArea.modelToView(0).height / 2;
int offset = textArea.viewToModel( new Point(width, height) );
int start = Utilities.getPreviousWord( offset );  // or maybe getWordStart(...)?
int end = Utilitities.getWordEnd( start );
String text = textArea.getText(start, end - start);
```

Comment: this is working thanks for it :) But this is only for the first line if I see it right? Do I have to change the 
int height = textArea.modelToView(0).height / 2;
to
int height = textArea.modelToView(0).height / 3;
when I Have more rows?

Comment: The height from the Rectangle returned in the modelToView(...) method will give you the height of a line. So you can multiple by the row number to get the appropriate y value.

Answer (score 0):

Split your string by the space character, and then locate the last element of the array. A simple example:

```
String myString = "foo bar foo bar";
String[] stuff = myString.split(" ");
String last = stuff[stuff.length-1];
```

The result for the "last" String would be "bar".

Edit: The link provided in the comment below should be helpful as well if you're having an issue finding a break point character to split by: [How to get line-wrapped text from JTextArea into multiple line-seperated Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31519473/how-to-get-line-wrapped-text-from-jtextarea-into-multiple-line-seperated-strings/31519905#31519905)

Comment: probably wont work because the whole string is 1 line even if it gets a visual line break in it

Comment: @XtremeBaumer The visual break still has to be a line break character of some kind. If you're implying nextLine() won't work, then split the entire big string by the line break character, then split those smaller strings by a space. Not a big deal, it's just one more level of split.

Comment: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31519473/how-to-get-line-wrapped-text-from-jtextarea-into-multiple-line-seperated-strings/31519905#31519905)